# elastic beanstalk/nginx multiple ssl domain redirect to another one

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to redirect domain.net and domain.fr to www.domain.me with this (https) :

```
upstream nodejsserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  .domain.fr .domain.net;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://domain.me/$1 permanent;
}
```

It still doesn't work. Nginx is on elastic beanstalk and my ssl certificate is managed by Certificate Manager.